# What does the & symbol mean in this TSQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rightfax

I have been working on some reports and recently found a small guide for the system I have been querying against. Part of the syntax it offers up is like the following:

```
... "WHERE [FIELD] & [VALUE] = [VALUE]"
```

i.e.: `... "WHERE flags & 16 = 16"`

I am just curious as to what this syntax is meaning... I get something like WHERE flags = 16, but not the '&16 = 16' part. Any clarification?

The article referenced: http://rightfaxapi.com/advanced-sql-for-manipulating-faxes/

Thank you,
Wes

Comment: That's a [bitwise AND operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) Detailed info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: absent any context, the title "Advanced SQL for Manipulating Faxes" is kind of terrifying.

Comment: Like "Making Peanut Butter Sandwiches with JavaScript" :)

Comment: haha. sorry Michael. It's for a system called RightFax. It stored fax details in a SQL Server Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` is doing a bit-wise "and".  So, it is "1" only when both bits are 1.  The logic overall is checking that all the bits in `value` are set in `field`.

As an example, consider that `value` is:

```
0000 0101
```

Then if field is

```
1111 1111
```

The `&` is:

```
0000 0101
```

(The `1`s are only where both are `1`.)

And this is the same as `value`.  So, this passes the condition.

Now if `field` is:

```
0001 1110
```

Then the `&` is:

```
0000 0100
```

And this differs from `value`, so it does not pass the condition.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Really appreciate the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

`&` is bitwise AND. In your example, your *mask* is 16(0x0010, binary 0000 0000 0001 0000 ).  The reslt of the AND operation will be either 0 (all bits in the mask are not set) or the mask value (all bit in the mask ARE set). So your `where A&16 = 16` expression is testing to see if bit 5 of the integer value, counting from the right, is set.

Examples:

- `48 & 16 = 16` is TRUE:

  ```
      48 (binary: 0000 0000 0011 0000)
  AND 16 (binary: 0000 0000 0001 0000)
      -- -----------------------------
      16 (binary: 0000 0000 0001 0000)
  ```
- `33 & 16 = 16` is FALSE:

  ```
      33 (binary: 0000 0000 0010 0001)
  AND 16 (binary: 0000 0000 0001 0000)
      -- -----------------------------
       0 (binary: 0000 0000 0000 0000)
  ```

Easy!